# I need to install php version 7.2.17 on wamp server for magento 2

Tags: wampserver

I need to install php version 7.2.17 on wamp server for magento 2. I am suffering with this.

Is anyone have solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Use this update if you have WAMPServer 64bit

```
http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/php/wampserver3_x64_addon_php7.2.17.exe
```

or this one if you have WAMPServer 32bit

```
http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/php/wampserver3_x86_addon_php7.2.17.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you suffering with?

If your wamp/xampp has a wrong PHP version, try downloading a different one. They usually have section where you can check out older versions with different PHP versions.

I didn't find one for wamp, but I personally use XAMPP - here is XAMPP download link with the PHP version you asked:
[Download XAMPP with PHP 7.2.17](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.2.17/)

Comment: WAMPServer 3 can install ADDONS for alsmost any version of PHP without having to install the whole eco system like XAMPP